# Replace a part of string if it is followed by /,- or * in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

i am quit new to Python and also in stack overflow. This platform is quit helpful for me to get what i wanted to perform code wise. I am working on a dataframe in pandas and I want to replace a part of string only if it is followed by `/ or - or *`.  the sample string is-
 `MAA-BOM/MADRAS`.
 I want to replace `MAA to MADRAS, BOM to BOMBAY, MAD to MADRID`. so the desired output will be like `MADRAS-BOMBAY/MADRAS`.  I want only `MAA and BOM to be replaced while MAD in MADRAS should remain intact`. I was using `.replace()` with dictionary  but this is not giving me desired output. 
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would personally try and build a regex for this. I recommend regex101.com to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a dictionary of mappings:

```
m = {'MAA' : 'MADRAS', 'BOM': 'BOMBAY', 'MAD' : 'MADRID'}
```

Now, call `str.replace` on your column:

```
df['Col'] = df['Col'].str.replace(r'.*?(?=[/*-])', 
                        lambda x: m.get(x.group(), None))
```

Comment: Hi @COLDSPEED, thanks for the response. I have tried your code but I am getting error: <br/> `repl must be a string`. <br/> the code i am using is : <br/> <`iata_dict = dict(zip(df7.CityCode, df7.CityName))   #creating dict from dataframe for 8K+ key value pairs.

df6["Itinerary"] = df6["Itinerary"].str.replace(r'.*?(?=[/*-])', lambda x: iata_dict.get(x, None))

df6`> <br/>  I have 8k+ key value pairs.

Comment: @anandpran Your version of pandas is _out of date_. Please upgrade to the latest - 0.20 using `pip install --upgrade pandas`. Callbacks are not supported on older versions.

Comment: @anandpran Also, see I had to add `.group`, please see my edit and incorporate it. Thanks.